# Probability CDF and PDF random variable convert

Tags: probability

Let X be a random variable with density function $f(x)=\frac{2x}{9}$, for $0 \le x \le 3$, otherwise is $0$.

Find the density function of $Y=X(X-3)$.
I tried to plug in $0$ and $3$ to find the range of $Y$ but it doesn't work (usually it works) and I saw the solution, did the derivative, and found that the minimum is $-\frac{9}{4}$, so $y$ is in the interval $(-\frac{9}{4}, 0)$. However, why is it not $(-\frac{9}{4}, 3)$?

Comment: We can't read your mind. Firstly, where is the solution? Can you put a link to the solution in your question? Also, why do you say that plugging $0$ and $3$ to find the range of $Y$ usually works?

Comment: Please also learn [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It would be much easier for us to answer your question if we didn't have to keep commenting to suggest some improvements. Please actively learn the rules of Math SE: the [help page](https://math.stackexchange.com/help) is a great place to start.

Answer (score 1):

If $0\leqslant x\leqslant 3$, then $-3\leqslant x-3\leqslant 0$, so $x(x-3)\leqslant 0$. Now, at $x=3$ and $x=0$ we have $x(x-3)=0$. Let $g(x) = x(x-3)$. Since $g$ is continuous on $[0,3]$, it has a minimum value, and because it is differentiable on $(0,3)$, that minimum value must be obtained at a point where $g'(x)=0$ (since $g(x)=0$ on the boundary of $(0,3)$ and $g(x)<0$ on the interior of $(0,3)$). We have $$g'(x) = x-3 + x = 2x-3,$$ so $g'(x) = 0$ if and only if $x = \frac32$. Indeed, $$g\left(\frac32\right) = \frac32\left(\frac32-3\right) = -\frac94.$$ So $Y=X(X-3)$ takes values on $\left(-\frac94,0\right)$.

Comment: LeT ME REPEAT THE QUESTION, WHY NOT(-9/4,3)

Comment: There is no need for all caps. We have $x\leqslant 3$ and $x-3\leqslant 0$, thus multiplying the inequalities yields $x(x-3)\leqslant 0$.